# Get column value from table across all databases on server with SQL command?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have about 50 WordPress databases on a server. I need to quickly pull all values for `admin_email` from the `wp_options` table across each database.

What I'm hoping for is something like:

```
-- psuedocode, not sure how to correctly format something like this
foreach database in database_names
    SELECT `option_value` FROM `wp_options`
    WHERE `option_name`='admin_email';
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. I saw other questions recommending using the `information_schema` table, but all of my `schemata.schema_name` values are in the format of 'db_structure.php?db=db_name&token=some_token' --- I'm not sure if this is expected, and if so, how one would go about looping through each database name.

I'm using phpMyAdmin as my DB administration tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can occupy a query in sql that returns you all list with UNION

```
SELECT email FROM dbo.tbname1
UNION
SELECT email FROM dbo.tbname2
UNION
SELECT email FROM dbo.tbname3
```